# How to repeat YoYo Animation Techniques infinite times?

Tags: android, animation, infinite

***Hi everyone..***

I'm using very nice animation techniques from [Github](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidViewAnimations). This guy provide us very nice  text effect and i like to use some of them for infinite times not only if User pressed that particular button and then play that effect.

here is my code:

```
 private YoYo.YoYoString rope;

 rope = YoYo.with(Techniques.RollOut)
        .duration(1200)
        .interpolate(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator())
        .withListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {}

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {}

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {}

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {}
        }).playOn(mTarget);
```

So here is my problem when I'm going to add this code at onAnimationEnd method:

```
animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
```

there will be error and it said: *"The method setRepeatCount(int) is undefined for the type Animator"*.

If you want to proceed please go to [Github](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidViewAnimations) address I've provided.
So, again in short, i want to repeat an animation infinite times.

Answer (score 3):

I use repeat method like this.

```
YoYo.with(Techniques.Tada)
    .duration(700)
    .repeat(Animation.INFINITE)
    .playOn(...);
```

Answer (score 2):

This trick works for me. Try

```
YoYo.with(Techniques.RollOut)
    .duration(1200) 
    .interpolate(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator())
    .withListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {

        @Override 
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {}

        @Override 
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
          YoYo.with(Techniques.RollOut)
          .duration(1200) 
          .interpolate(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator())
          .withListener(this).playOn(mTarget);
       }

        @Override 
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {}

        @Override 
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {}
    }).playOn(mTarget);
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way with countDownTimer:

```
private void countDownForCustomAnimation(final int time){
    new  CountDownTimer(time, time){

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            if(!isMainClickedYet){ 
               YoYo.with(Techniques.RollOut)
              .duration(timeforDuration)
              .playOn(view);
               countDownForCustomAnimation(time);
            }
        }

    }.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the code below to repeat animation :

```
    YoYo.with(Techniques.Wobble)
            .repeat(YoYo.INFINITE)
            .duration(5000)
            .playOn(imgCycleRoad);
```